# How can I test the correct exception was raised for a function that was partially successful in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a function whose core structure is as follows:

```py
def download_remote_directory(dir_path):
    files = list_files(dir_path)
    results = []
    try:
        for f in files:
            results.append(download_file(f))
    except Exception as e:
        if results:
            raise PartialDownloadException()
        raise e
    return results
```

I want to test that the `PartialDownloadException` is raised if `results` is a non-empty list.

I am using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/) for testing my code. I am thinking the correct solution will somehow use [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html), but nothing I have tried works so far.

Edit: For clarification, I want the `PartialDownloadException` to get raised from the `download_remote_directory` function after the `download_file` function has been executed at least once. I know how to check whether the exception was raised in my test code; I am not sure how to raise the error in the first place.

Comment: I assume your question is how to induce a failure in `download_file` after at least one successful download?

Comment: @chepner, yes, I want to induce the failure in `download_remote_directory` (assuming you had a typo there) after at least one successful download.

Comment: No, I meant `download_file`, as that's the function that will raise an except that can result in `results` being non-empty when the exception is caught.

Comment: Imagine: the first time `download_file` is called, it succeeds. Now `results` has one item. The second time it is called, it raises an exception; now, `results` is not empty and thus you'll raise `PartialDownloadExeption`. If `download_file` *always* succeeds, you'll just return `results`, and if it *never* succeeds, you'll just raise whatever exception `download_file` itself raised, not `PartialDownloadException`.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are correct @chepner

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pytest's `raises`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) like so

```py
with pytest.raises(PartialDownloadException):
    download_remote_directory(path_that_fails)
```

The above will fail if `download_remote_directory` does not raise `PartialDownloadException`.

To modify and/or count the number of executions, you can use `unittest.mock.patch`. Here's a complete example, assuming your code lives in the `implementation` module.

```py
import implementation
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch


def test_download_remote_directory():
    # Patch "list_files" to return a known list.
    with patch("implementation.list_files", return_value=["a", "b", "c"]):
        # Patch download_file so we can check how many times it was called.
        with patch("implementation.download_file") as _download_file:
            implementation.download_remote_directory("foobar")
        assert _download_file.call_count == 3

        # Patch download_file so it raises an exception on the third call.
        with patch("implementation.download_file", side_effect=[None, None, RuntimeError()]):
            with pytest.raises(implementation.PartialDownloadException):
                implementation.download_remote_directory("foobar")
        assert _download_file.call_count == 3
```

In particular, we're using [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect)s to modify the behavior of `download_file` on each execution. The documentation explains it better than I can:

> If you pass in an iterable *[to `side_effect`]*, it is used to retrieve an iterator which must yield a value on every call. This value can either be an exception instance to be raised, or a value to be returned from the call to the mock

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am actually asking for a different thing. Please see the edit on my question.

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional details regarding testing.

Comment: Thank you for the updated and concise answer! As far as I understand, patching the `download_file` function this way won't run the actual `download_file` function. I wanted some files to be actually downloaded before `PartialDownloadException` was raised for some other tests.

Comment: This is certainly feasible (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933411/how-can-i-run-a-function-to-get-side-effects-when-a-python-mock-is-called), but I'd recommend testing `download_file` independently.

Answer (score 0):

This code will test if `PartialDownloadException` was raised. If raises the test will pass else it'll throw error.

Reference: [pytest(expected-exceptions)](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions), [pytest.raises()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.raises)

```py
def test_partial_download(self, args):
    with pytest.raises(PartialDownloadException):
        # your code
        ...
        download_remote_directory(error_path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am actually asking for a different thing. Please see the edit on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following solution for my situation:

```py
import pytest
import functools

class PartialDownloadException(Exception):
    pass

class Downloader:

    @staticmethod
    def list_files(dir_path):
        return [f'{dir_path}/file{i}' for i in range(3)]

    @staticmethod
    def download_file(file_path):
        print(f'Downloaded {file_path}')
        return file_path

    @staticmethod
    def download_remote_directory(dir_path):
        files = Downloader.list_files(dir_path)
        results = []
        try:
            for f in files:
                results.append(Downloader.download_file(f))
        except Exception as e:
            if results:
                raise PartialDownloadException()
            raise e
        return results

def count_calls(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_count_calls(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper_count_calls.num_calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper_count_calls.num_calls = 0
    return wrapper_count_calls

def raise_exception_after_n_calls(func, n):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_raise_exception_after_n_calls(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper_raise_exception_after_n_calls.num_calls += 1
        if wrapper_raise_exception_after_n_calls.num_calls == n:
            raise Exception()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper_raise_exception_after_n_calls.num_calls = 0
    return wrapper_raise_exception_after_n_calls

def test_download_remote_directory(monkeypatch):
     assert Downloader.download_remote_directory('dir') == ['dir/file0', 'dir/file1', 'dir/file2']

     with monkeypatch.context() as m:
         m.setattr(Downloader, 'download_file', count_calls(Downloader.download_file))
         Downloader.download_remote_directory('dir')
         assert Downloader.download_file.num_calls == 3

     with monkeypatch.context() as m:
            m.setattr(Downloader, 'download_file', raise_exception_after_n_calls(Downloader.download_file, 2))
            with pytest.raises(PartialDownloadException):
                Downloader.download_remote_directory('dir')
            assert Downloader.download_file.num_calls == 2
```

I have kept all the code in the same file for the sake of simplicity in this example.

Here's a breakdown of what I have done:

1. I have moved the functions I asked about earlier into the class `Downloader` and provided dummy implementations for the `Downloader` and `PartialDownloadException` class.
2. Just to demonstrate how calls to a function can be counted, I have included a `count_calls` function (based on the example given [here](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20next%20section%2C%20you%20will%20see%20how%20to%20use%20classes%20to%20keep%20state.%20But%20in%20simple%20cases%2C%20you%20can%20also%20get%20away%20with%20using%20function%20attributes%3A)).
3. Finally, I have implemented the `raise_exception_after_n_calls` function which raises an exception after the function `func` has executed `n` times.

My thanks to @chepner for their helpful comments.